# Find word next to some symbol

Tags: jquery

If I have a `<textarea>` and I type `#SomeName is very happy today! #AnotherName`, I want to make `var name = #SomeName` or `#AnotherName`. I want to store in the `name` var only word that is next to `#`. Can someone tell me how to do it in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that there could be an unlimited number of `#` values in the string within the textarea I would suggest you create an array to contain them all instead of a single string. With that in mind you can use a Regular Expression and the `match()` method. Try this:

```
var matches = textareaValue.match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ncatktqa/)

The first part of the Regex is a negative lookahead to ensure the `#` is preceded by a space. The second part is retrieving the actual value.

Comment: It wont be I need to find word next to # with # itself and after finding it I will replace it with something else and again when # is typed and word with that next to it....

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Btw it helps can you send me link or explanation about this?
match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig);

Comment: You didnt answeer me what I wanted to but with ssome change it can help a lot just I need to know about match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig); so i can use it more...

Comment: I need this for tagging system like on facebook, I made it like after keypress 35 which is # show me div list, and cuz of that I need word next to # to find Name in database with keyup